# Dependence of one Observable on another RxJava2

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

There is a class, it has observable fields. I want to update `localData`

when receiving remote data `remoteData`, for some reason I can not get data in `localData`, debugging does not go to a breakpoint even to `getIdsInDatumsRemote ()`. The `identifyDatumsForUpdate ()` method gets an empty Observable.

```
class DiskDatumDataStore {

    var remoteData: Observable<Data>? = null

    var localData: Observable<Data>? = null

    override fun sync() {
        remoteDatums = getChangedRemoteData(lastUpdated!!, 1000)!!
        localDatums = remoteDatums!!.map {
            getIdsInDatumsRemote(it)
        }.map {
            it.map {
                it.toLong()
            }
        }.flatMap {
            getOldLocalData(it)
        }


        identifyDatumsForUpdate(datumsForUpdateLocal, datumsForUpdateRemote)
    }

    override fun getOldLocalData(remoteDatumsIds: List<Long>): Observable<List<DataLayerTypesOfResponsibility>> {
        return Observable.fromCallable { repository.getOldDatum(remoteDatumsIds) }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not `subscribing` to your `Observable`. You're just creating it.

```
localDatums = remoteDatums!!.map {
            getIdsInDatumsRemote(it)
        }.map {
            it.map {
                it.toLong()
            }
        }.flatMap {
            getOldLocalData(it)
        }.subscribe { it->
            //do something with the result `it`
        }
```